# Filling the HttpResponce csv data in excel - VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

In my case i'm calling the HttpRequest to get the result `result = winHttpReq.responseText` .result is actually a string.I'm getting the result as a comma separated format string while the woorkbook is loading itself.I want to display these text starting from particular row,column in my excel as row by row manner.I was separated the each line by `"\n"` in response string.

It have to fill while the wookbook is loading ` Workbook_Open()`.What is the simple solution to do this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the HTTPResponse into an ADODB Recordet you can use CopyFromRecordset method.

alternatively, if you can get the XLHTTPResponse as XML Data then Excel should be able to treat it as data